# Highlight entire line in a nested list on hover

Tags: html, css

## Context

I've `<li><div></div></li>` elements with a background color on hover.

It looks like :

[image]

I want to color the full line, like :

[image]

## Investigation

The code:

```
div.wrapper:hover {
  background: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.3);
}
```

I tried this, without success:

```
div.wrapper:hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.3);
}
```

## Question

How can I do this?

Comment: Need more HTML to see what 'whole line' is

Comment: Also, setting the height to 0 probably isn't helping ;)

Comment: Does the `li` span all the way from left/right? If it doesn't, not sure how you're going to accomplish that.

Comment: How does this relate to jQuery?

Comment: Why did you delete the `<li>` from your question? Was that not your real markup?

Comment: The `<li>` wraps sub-elements. So to get lines, the hover is on the `<div>`.

Comment: @Phrogz - GG responded to your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove all margins from your ul/li, set your content wrappers to `display:block`, and then put `padding` on those elements based on the nesting level: http://jsfiddle.net/dYdQB/

**HTML**

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Hello</span></li>
  <li><span>World</span><ul>
    <li><span>Nested deeper</span></li>
    <li><span>And again</span><ul>
      <li><span>And Even Deeper</span></li>
    </ul></li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>
​
```

**CSS**

```css
ul, li { margin:0; padding:0 }
ul li span { display:block }
ul li span:hover { background:orange }
li span       { padding-left:2em }
li li span    { padding-left:4em }
li li li span { padding-left:6em }​
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do it with ::before - check following solution can help.

http://jsfiddle.net/t3SvL/3/

Comment: This is an excellent answer if you can't change the html code! Helped me a lot.